# How tell the python logging if its actually running?

Tags: python, linux, logging, parallel-processing, python-logging

I work at Linux
I have function which calculate some data and brings me results.
This function running in parallel in many copies on many workers in the local web.
I pass the function to the program which manages tasks for workers.
I need to have logging in that function.
I set logging_manager.py and have proper configuration in it - RotatingFileHandler (3 mb for every file, 99 log files max) - Rotating file handler makes the logs size stable - i cant get more than 300 mb for logs

But when I set logging in the beginning of the function - it sets new root logger for every parallel execution and in time every logger opens a file and it exceeds maximum process number which can be handled on machine and then crashing. Also huge amount of logs makes my log files messy because every logger tries to log to the same file but they don't know about each other.

This situation slows me down. I don't like it.

If i set logger to log to new file every time - i will quickly have space exceed on my machine and need to clean it by hand or set service to do it for me - i don't want such a thing

I tried to set logger as a process and manage logs with Queue, but then again - i need to code it on that function, so result will be the same - new process for every file.  Loggers don't know about each other.

So my question is:

How tell the process if similar process already exists and force it to connect to previous logger process queue instead of creating new, separate process with separate queue?

This is something like centralized python logging service for the machine which will handle all my parallel functions and properly manage log messages in the files.

Is it even possible? Or do I need to find different solution?

Comment: syslogd already does all of this. Use it.

Comment: Ehh... I was afraid of that answer... Okay lets start learning

Comment: python logging has a syslog handler. makes this pretty easy: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#sysloghandler